# How to refresh gtk widget (gtk_widget_queue_draw error)

Tags: c++, c, gtk

I have a simple gtk window with one image in it. After making some modification on that image (taken from OpenCV) I want to make window refresh by expose-event. I use gtk2 and it is not possible to change to gtk3. There is no errors but image is not redrawn, the old one still persist.

```
class TestApp {
    public:
        GtkWidget *frameWindow;
        GInputStream *inStr;
        GtkWidget *image;
        GdkPixbuf *pixBuff;
        cv::Mat *frame;

        TestApp(int argc, char *argv[]) : frameWindow(NULL), image(NULL), pixBuff(NULL), inStr(NULL),frame(NULL){
            gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
        } 

        int refresh(cv::Mat *f){
            frame=f;
            int sz = f->dataend - f->datastart;
            memcpy((uchar*)gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels(pixBuff),f->datastart,sz);
            gtk_widget_queue_draw(frameWindow);
            return 0;
        }

        void imshow(cv::Mat *im){
            /* main window */
            frame = im;
            frameWindow = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
            gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(frameWindow), 1);
            gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(frameWindow), "image");
            gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(frameWindow), 1280, 720);
            gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(frameWindow), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
            gtk_window_fullscreen(GTK_WINDOW(frameWindow));

            pixBuff=gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data((guchar*)im->datastart,GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB,FALSE,8,im->size().width,im->size().height,(im->channels()*im->cols), NULL,NULL);
            image = gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf(pixBuff);
            gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(frameWindow), image);

            g_object_ref_sink(G_OBJECT(frameWindow));
            g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(frameWindow), "expose_event", G_CALLBACK((void*)exposeCb), (gpointer)this);
            g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(frameWindow), "key_press_event", G_CALLBACK((void*)buttonCb), (gpointer)this);
            gtk_widget_realize(frameWindow); 
            gtk_widget_show_all(frameWindow);
            gtk_main();
        }

        static gboolean buttonCb(GtkWidget *eventBox, GdkEventKey *event, gpointer data){
            char c = event->keyval;
            switch(c){
                case 'q':
                    gtk_widget_destroy(eventBox);
                    gtk_main_quit();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

        static gboolean exposeCb(GtkWidget *eventBox, GtkWidget *event, gpointer data){
            return false;
        }
};

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    TestApp gtkObj(argc,argv);
    cv::Mat im=cv::imread("colour256.png");
    cv::Mat imOld=im.clone();
    cv::cvtColor(im,im,CV_BGR2RGB);
    gtkObj.imshow(&im); 
    gtkObj.refresh(&imOld);
    return 0;
}
```

Should I redraw image somehow?

Comment: Welcome to SO! We generally like to keep it to one question per post. Also, your paragraph at the top doesn't seem to really relate to what you then ask as the questions. It *seems* like the question should be "How do I refresh a GTK window?" or similar.

Comment: Ok, I found smaller scope of the problem. Please find my question revisited above.

Comment: The gtk_main() call inside imshow() will block your program until gtk_main_quit() is called. You may want to schedule the refresh using g_idle_add() before you call gtk_main().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `FALSE` is correct return value. Returning `TRUE` means "I have dealt with this event" so no further callbacks for particular event ("signal" in GTK+ parlance) are called, in particular default callback is not called so window is not painted. Returning `FALSE` doesn't stop other callbacks.
2. I don't think there's much difference. Id' leave it in `refresh` in order to avoid doing too much work in callbacks.
3. Quoted warning means that pointer passed to `gtk_widget_queue_draw` does not contain a `GtkWidget`. Maybe it hot corrupt? Maybe `refresh` is called prior to `imshow`?

Comment: Ad.1: Thanks a lot for making it clear. Ad.3: I must admit that this answer turned out to be very helpful yet. I've changed my code but it still does not work as it's supposed to do. However, the number of possible reasons is reduced now, I hope. If you could help I would be so thankful.